# httppost in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

Am having data in xml format and have to send it through httppost server in vc++ 
I tried lot of links but for vc++ cant get any good guidance for my knowledge as am new to this
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you could use mfc, try CHttpFile. Or you should use wininet.dll